# Angularjs - Accessing shared service data from an ng-repeated directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create drag-drop directives using Angularjs. Draggables in this scenario are generated by an ng-repeat directive, walking over an array. Code at  http://jsbin.com/ECAWuDE/1/edit works as expected. But it requires a wrapping parent scope for draggables.

When I try to get rid of the wrapping scope by using a service (http://jsbin.com/AJoTIw/2/edit), I can no longer access the array.

What am I doing wrong in second version of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, your binding are evaluated in context of `$scope` variable. You cannot have a service and direct bind to its data. So actually you need a wrapping element. So either you use div or any parent of the repeat element. I have updated you jsbin see [here](http://jsbin.com/AJoTIw/8/edit).

You can still do it without the service, by using the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to change your code to use the service and it's working now.

I've created a new directive called 'make-it-drag' and it makes each element of the 'ng-repeat' of the draggables directive to be... erm... draggable. ;)

So I used the 'draggables' **controller** function only to set the `$scope.blocks` value with the data returned by the service.
The 'make-it-drag' directive is then responsible to do all the events binding.

You can see the code below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>

<style type="text/css">
.droppable {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.draggable, .dropped {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.green {background-color: green;}
.blue {background-color: blue;}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('makeItDrag', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {

       elm.attr("draggable", true);

       elm.bind("dragstart", function(evt){
        evt.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", JSON.stringify(scope.bl));
       });

       elm.bind("dragend", function(evt){
           var data = evt.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
           console.log(data);
       });
     }
   };
 }])

myApp.directive('draggables', [ 'crmService' ,function (crmService) {
  return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
    console.log('I am draggable', crmService.blocks);
  },
  controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){

    $scope.blocks = crmService.blocks;

  }
};
}])
myApp.directive('droppables', [ 'crmService', function (crmService) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
    console.log('I am droppable', crmService.blocks);

    scope._blocks = [];
    elm.bind("drop", function(evt){
      // redirecti engelliyoruz
      evt.preventDefault();
      data  = JSON.parse(evt.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain"));
      // directive ve ng-repeat konusunda bir sıkıntı var,
      // ng-repeat ile yeni yerel scopayar oluştuğu için sanıyorum 
      // ki apply gerekiyor 
      scope.$apply(function(){
          scope._blocks.push({color: data.color, name:data.name})
      });

      return false;

    });
    elm.bind("dragover", function(evt){
        // bu kısmın droppable olduğunu gösteriyor
        evt.preventDefault();
    });
    elm.bind("dragenter", function(){
        console.log("enter");
    });

    elm.bind("dragleave", function(){
        console.log("leave");
    });
    }
    };
}])

myApp.factory("crmService", function(){
return {
    blocks: [
        {"color": "green", name:"resim 1" },
        {"color": "blue", name:"resim 2" }
    ]
 }
})

</script>


</head>
<body>

<div draggables>
  <div class="draggable {{ bl.color }} " ng-repeat="bl in blocks" make-it-drag></div>
</div>

<div droppables class="droppable"> 
  <div droppable="true" class="dropped {{ _bl.color }}" ng-repeat="_bl in _blocks">
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

P.S.: By the way I've added an 's' to the name of the directives (draggable**s** / droppable**s**) as they were HTML5 reserved words - not a good practice to use reserved words.

Comment: @Chandermani has a good explanation and simpler solution for the issue. But I will leave this answer as another alternative.